# Where to find events list for Corona SDK?

Tags: coronasdk

I need something to be called when any physics property is changed to synchronize objects those are physical bodies and those are not. It turned out that enterFrame works less frequently than velocity changes.
Where can I find full corona SDK events list? This: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Event.html wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the page you are looking for: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For whole list you can prefer - http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/ and for using custom events, you can use - http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/06/26/how-to-use-custom-events-in-corona/